Two definition of radial functions
I have a problem understanding how these two definitions of radial functions in $\mathbb R ^n$ are equivalent.
We can say that a measurable $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is radial if there exist a $g:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$  measurable such that $f(x) = g(|x|)$ for a.e. $x\in\mathbb R$.
The other definition is that for every orthogonal matrix $O$ we have $f(x) = f(Ox)$ a.e..
Now, it is easy to see that definition 1 implies definition 2, but what about the opposite direction? I can't really figure out how to define $g$, cause the obvious thing to to is to define it as $f$ restricted to some line, but having a line measure 0 it is not clear that $g$ will have that good property.
I also tried to define $g(r) = \frac{1}{|\partial B_r|}\int_{\partial B_r}f d\sigma_{n-1}$, but it is again not clear that $\tilde {f} (x) = g(|x|)$ is a.e. equal to $f$.
How can I formally prove that the two definitions are equal? I really can't go around these measure theoretic details.

I'm sure the proof is just a clever way to use the idea of this other post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060375/a-function-constant-almost-everywhere. But I can't find the right way to do it.

Let $G$ be a compact Hausdorff group and $\lambda$ the normalized Haar measure on $G$. Let $G$ act on a measure space $(X,\mu)$. Let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ measureable such that for all $g \in G$ $f(gx) = f(x)$ $\mu$-a.e. Then there is some measureable $F: X \to \mathbb{R}$ with $F(gx) = F(x)$ for all $x \in X$ and $g \in G$ and such that $F = f$ $\mu$-a.e.
Construct $F$ as follows: define $F(x) := \int_G f(gx) d\lambda(g)$. Then $F(gx) = \int_G f(g'gx) d\lambda(g')=\int_G f(g'x) d\lambda(g') = F(x)$ for all $x \in X$ and $g \in G$, since $\lambda$ is $G$-left invariant.
Now it holds $F = f$ $\mu$-a.e. $\iff$ $\int_X F(x)\phi(x)d\mu(x) = \int_{X}f(x)\phi(x)d\mu(x)$ for all $\phi$. But this holds by Fubinis Theorem:
$$\int_X F(x)\phi(x)d\mu(x) = \int_X \int_G f(gx)\phi(x)d\lambda(g)d\mu(x) = \int_G \int_X f(gx)\phi(x)d\mu(x)d\lambda(g) \\
= \int_G \int_X f(x)\phi(x)d\mu(x)d\lambda(g) = \int_X f(x)\phi(x)d\mu(x) \int_G 1 d\lambda(g) \\
= \int_{X}f(x)\phi(x)d\mu(x).$$
Now take in the above situation $G = O(n)$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Lebesgue measure. Find $F$ as above for the given $f$. Then it is $F(Ax) = F(x)$ for all $A \in O(n)$ and $F = f$ a.e.. Define $g(r) := F(r,0\dots,0)$ for $r \geq 0$. Then $F(x) = g(|x|)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and therefore $f(x) = g(|x|)$ for a.e. $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ .
