# Showing that $f*\phi_t\to af$ in $\|\cdot\|_p$ as $t\to\infty$ with $f,\phi$ as given

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, convolution

From Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications* there is the following result:

> **Folland, Theorem 8.14, (a):** Suppose that $\phi\in L^1$ and $\int\phi(x)\text{d}x=a$. If $f\in L^p$ for $1\le p<\infty$ then $f*\phi_t\to af$ in $\|\cdot\|_p$ as $t\to\infty$.

Here, $\phi_t(x)=t^{-n}\phi(t^{-1}x)$. The proof of a variant of this problem is asked and discussed here: [Why convolution of integrable function f
with some sequence tends to f
a.e.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170433/why-convolution-of-integrable-function-f-with-some-sequence-tends-to-f-a-e?rq=1)

I am interested in another variant of this problem, and have followed the proof outlined in Folland, but am now at a point where I am not sure how to continue. I feel that I am very close to drawing out the result I need.

In my variation of the problem, I have $\phi_n(x):=n\phi(nx)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ where $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$, $\phi(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, the support of $\phi$ is contained in $[-1,1]$ and $\int_\mathbb{R}\phi(x)\text{d}x=1$. I am concerned with the particular case when $p=2$

Here is my attempt so far. We want to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f*\phi_n-f\|_2=0$, so begin by considering what $\|f*\phi_n-f\|_2$  looks like. We obtain,
$$\|(f*\phi_n)(x)-f(x)\|_2=\left(\int_{\mathbb R}\left|\int_\mathbb{R} n\phi(ny)\left[\tau_y\left(f(x)\right)-f(x)\right])\,\text{d}y\right|^2\,\text{d}x\right)^{1/2},$$
where $\tau_y$ denotes the translation of $f$ by $y$, i.e. $\tau_y\left(f(x)\right)=f(x-y)$. By Minkowski's integral inequality, we obtain that,
$$\left(\int_{\mathbb R}\left|\int_\mathbb{R} n\phi(ny)\left[\tau_y\left(f(x)\right)-f(x)\right])\,\text{d}y\right|^2\,\text{d}x\right)^{1/2}\le\int_\mathbb{R}|n\phi(ny)|\|\tau_y\left(f(x)\right)-f(x)\|_2\text{d}y\le 2\|f\|_2,$$

where we have made use of the fact that $\|\tau_y\left(f(x)\right)-f(x)\|_2\le2\|f(x)\|_2$. Note that this leaves only $\int_\mathbb{R}|n\phi(ny)|\text{d}y$, which we can integrate with the substitution $y=s/n$ to see that this integral is 1.

Putting this all together, we now have that,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f*\phi_n-f\|_2\le2\|f(x)\|_2.$$
I don't think that I can apply LDCT because of the factor of $n$ in $n\int_\mathbb{R}\phi(ny)\text{d}y$. Although, we do have at least that the limit of the integral of this sequence *is* bounded. Can we work with this somehow to draw out the result we need? Or is this the incorrect way to go about the problem?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that I follow your comment. I have managed to figure it out - I will post it up once I get the chance.

Comment: Assume $\lim_{k \to \infty} \|f-f_k\|_p = 0$ with the $f_k$ continuous, do you see that it is easy to show $\lim_{a \to 0}\|h(.+a)-h\|_p = 0$ and $\lim_{n \to 0}\|h \ast \phi_n-h\|_p = 0$ for $h = f_k$ thus also for $h = f$. In Lebesgue's framework, at first, the $f_k$ aren't continuous but are finite sums of simple functions, so you need to show simple functions are limits (in $L^p$ norm) of continuous functions.